# Using variable in array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Can someone help me how to change value of an array to variable?

I would like to change from this:

```
class SimpleAuth
{
var $users = array(
    'admin1' => 'password1',  //
    'admin2' => 'password2',  // User 2
    'admin3' => 'password3',  // User 3
    'admin4' => 'password4',  // User 4
);
}
```

to:

```
$user = 'admin'; // value from an include file outside the class declaration
$password = 'password'; // value from an include file outside the class declaration

class SimpleAuth
{
var $users = array(
    $user => $password,       // User 1 // here is the error
    'admin2' => 'password2',  // User 2
    'admin3' => 'password3',  // User 3
    'admin4' => 'password4',  // User 4
);
}
```

I get 500 error. Please help! Thanks

Comment: can you show the error? the error from the php error log

Comment: The only error I'm getting is because of the `var`.

Comment: Take a look at your server error log - that should tell you what's gone wrong.

Comment: The error is in the line before. See: http://codepad.org/xG5rrz9z

Comment: I have updated my question as I didn't know the class declaration makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this without `var`. `var` was used to declare class member variables prior to php 5. it is still supported for backward compatibility but it only has meaning inside a class context.

```
$users = array(
$user => $password,       // User 1 // here is the error
'admin2' => 'password2',  // User 2
'admin3' => 'password3',  // User 3
'admin4' => 'password4',  // User 4
```

);

UPDATE, you can't use dynamic values when your defining the class members, as the variables will have no values when the class gets initiated. move your assignment to the `__construct`. In your case the construct is same as your class name.

```
function className() {
         $user = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

     $this->users[$user] = $password;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's inside a class declaration

Comment: So I just put your code right before the class declaration? Sorry, I am a newbie :p I have just purchased these code from codecanyon for login authentication.

Comment: your class should have the class constructor, which is the initial function that gets called when you initiate the class. Look for a function inside the class which has the same name as the class name, if not look for a function named '__construct' in your class. The code i gave you needs to go inside that function.

Comment: Thanks! working on it but doesn't seems easy coz it has lots of functions inside the class. There is no function called '__construct' and neither has function SimpleAuth()

Comment: ok create a function called SimpleAuth and place it in there.

Comment: Hey! It seems to work but still not quite what I need. Inside the function, can I use $user = $userid and $password = $userpassword?. Coz the values of $userid and $userpassword are from an include file.

Comment: I managed to put the include file inside the function and now it works well! Thanks DevZer0

Answer (score 2):

I just checked this code:

```
$user = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

$users = array(
    $user => $password,       // User 1 // here is the error
    'admin2' => 'password2',  // User 2
    'admin3' => 'password3',  // User 3
    'admin4' => 'password4',  // User 4
);
```

on this site (http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and it was good, remove the "var" it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'var' in front of your $users variable instantiation